# JMeter View Results in table

Tags: rest, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running some tests on a rest client. When I started Jmeter, I also setup some listeners such as "View Results in a table". When I run a test. I dynamically see the table being populated.

On the bottom of the table, there is a small toolbar having elements such as

No. of samples, Latest sample, Average and Deviation.
What are these elements indicating?
No. of samples - Does it mean the total requests that have got the response?
Latest sample - Does it mean the latest request being sent?
Average - Average of what?
Deviation - No clue

[JMeter "View Results in Table" Bottom Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muG8N.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`View Results Table` uses lot of memory. Please check [JMeter best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) for the actual load test.

To understand about the metrics, add `Summary Report` to your test plan. (Right click on Thread Group > Add > Listener > Summary Report).

Here is the sample `Summary Report`.

[image: Summary Report]

Here is the `View Results in Table` for the same execution.

[image: View Results Table]

In this example,

> Latest sample : **last sampler's Sample Time (ms).**
>
> Average : a set of numerical values (in this context it is **sample time**), calculated by adding them together and dividing by the number of terms in the set.
>
> Deviation : **standard deviation of Sample Time (ms).** JMeter uses **STDEVP** function.
>
> No of Samples : Total number of requests/samplers triggered in the test plan. If you checked, Child Samples, then it will list only sub-samples instead of the main samples.

Here is the Excel sheet view of the results.

[image: Excel Sheet Formula]

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't use any listeners while your test is running](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing)
2. [Don't run your test in GUI mode, make sure you are running the test in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

In regards to your questions:

- `Latest sample` - basically latest sampler **Elapsed Time**
- `Average` - [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of response times for all samplers (sum of all samplers response time divided by their count)
- `Deviation` - [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) for all samplers

Check out [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for detailed explanation on the above and others metrics.